# Find $n$'s for which $P_n = (3^n - 1)/2$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the numbers $P_n = (3^n - 1)/2$. Find $n$'s for which $P_n$ is
prime. Prove that neither $P_{2n}$ nor $P_{5n}$ is prime.

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: The question is first which number n makes $P_n$ prime and then second to prove that $P_{2n}$ and $P_{5n}$ are not prime

Comment: Thoughts on the more general case? We know that if $n$ is com positive, then $P_n$ is composite. How about for primes?

Comment: You will have noted that composite $n$ give trouble. But  $\frac{3^{3}-1}{2}$ is prime,  $\frac{3^{5}-1}{2}$ isn't,  $\frac{3^{7}-1}{2}$ is, in fact is an interesting prime.  Don't know how many more you want.

Comment: @Steven: My point was that the sentences were more in the form of commands, rather than questions

Answer (score 2):

To prove $P_{2n},P_{5n}$ are not prime, note that $$\frac{3^{2}-1}{2}=4$$  $$\frac{3^{5}-1}{2}=121$$

and those numbers will be factors of your number, since $$a^n-1=(a-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k$$ Use the above with $a=3^{5},3^{2}$.

We can in general assert that

> **PROP** If $n$ is composite, then $P_n$ is composite.

**P** Write $n=pq$, with $p,q$ primes. Then

$$P_n=\frac{3^{qp}-1}2=\frac{3^{p}-1}2(1+3^q+3^{2q}+\cdots+3^{(p-1)q})$$

We can see $\dfrac{3^{p}-1}2=1+3+3^2+\cdots+3^{p-1}$, so $P_n$ is composite.

> **COR** If $P_n$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

Thus, you'll have to look at $P_p$ where $p$ is prime. *Careful*: this won't always yield a prime!

Answer (score 0):

$P_{2n}=\frac{9^n-1}{2}$ is a multiple of $4$ because $9^n\equiv 1\pmod 8$.
$P_{5n}=\frac{243^n-1}{2}$ is a multiple of $11^2$ because $243^n\equiv 1\pmod {121}$.

Otherwise, compute $P_n$ for $n=3, 7, 13, 71,103$, for example.

Comment: how can you show that for each of those n's $P_n$ is prime?